# Error when opening files from internet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

When I try to open an Office file from a link, the appropriate application (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) launches but it gives an error message

```
Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space
```

As unusual as it is for MS messages, this is an irrelevant message ;) The actual problem is it does not trust files from internet. If I download the same file locally and try to open it I an getting the same message. But if I right click -> Properties -> Security/Unblock -> check, everything is perfect so it a matter of security.

I remember it verified internet files upon launch. Is there a way to reactivate this behavior?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I recommend including part of the error in your question title.